# Print row values as lists iteratively without getting the column names

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get rows of a dataframe as separate lists. This list should only contain the values in a certain row for a certain number of rows. For instance, a dataframe that looks like the following should print out only the rows as lists one after the other:

#### Example dataframe

| Name | Age | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Michael | 5 | M |
| Fitz | 10 | F |

should print out

```py
[Michael, 5, M]
[Fitz, 10, F]
```

I know `df.loc[[1]]` prints out the first row, but it also prints out the column names. I am trying to get rid of the column names, and have a list of only row values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you can, you can join the rows into list with `DataFrame.apply` or just convert the DataFrame to list of rows

```py
cols = ['Name', 'Age', 'Gender']

out = df[cols].apply(list, axis=1)
# or
lsts = df[cols].values.tolist()
```

```
print(out)

0    [Michael, 5, M]
1      [Fitz, 10, F]
dtype: object

print(lsts)

[['Michael', 5, 'M'], ['Fitz', 10, 'F']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if it's a header or regular row you have two options:

```
# If the first row is a header row.

df.values.tolist()
```

```
# If the first row is a regular row. Where the [1:] determines how many of the rows 
# you want to remove.

df.values.tolist()[1:]
```

Both produce:

```
[['Michael', 5, 'M'], [10, 'F', 'Fitz']]
```